# I'd like to add an event listener to a custom column definition in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to add an event listener to an ag-grid header that fires when enter is pressed only when the column is currently focused in ag-grid. The reason for this is because I'm trying to open a custom modal. I already have it firing on an event click of the button I created. However, this is not accessible, so I need to be able to tab to it and then press enter to open the modal.

Currently I am using the headerComponentParams: template: to render the html necessary in the header.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to show my companies code.

Comment: @AndrewRichards Can you create a sample on stackblitz or plunker? then tell us the problem.

Comment: Actually I solved the issue just by adding an event listener to the proper div.